# Servlet cannot access data from bean

Tags: java, servlets, javabeans

I have a javabean called Userbean, where I store data for users.

```
public class UserBean
{
        public String uid;               //User ID
        public String password;          //Password    
        public String email;           //Email
        ...
        public UserBean() {}

        public void setUid(String str) {uid = str;}
        public String getUid() { return uid;}
        ...
```

I want to get tis data from a servlet, but in every servlet I must make a new Userbean and cannot use the "getData" methods. In a word, I cannot access data from a bean in a servlet. For exaple

```
String uid = userBean.getUid();
```

everytime returns

> java.lang.NullPointerException

The only way I can avoid this error is to use

```
userBean = new UserBean();
```

but I want to use the data that is already put in the bean and not to create a new one. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where/how are you storing UserBean? The HttpSession?

Comment: show the servlet and how it is called

Comment: I suggest you read an introductory book about Java, variables and objects before trying to develop servlets. web programming is a hard task, and you won't get far if you don't understand the basics.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree that reading books would help me, but I also believe that the best way to learn is to try things and learn during random projects. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed, but simple console-based programs are much easier to get right at the beginning, and are much easier to execute than servlets. Start with the simplest things you can imagine.

Comment: I doubt doing it as a console-based program first would help him here, since the confusion relates to the concept of the session which doesn't exist in a console program. A lot of people think beans magically get saved into and pulled out of the session. Probably because bean is treated as a magic buzzword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you first instantiate the bean and set the values in one servlet, if you want to be able to access it in other servlets without recreating it, you need to save it in the session:

```
UserBean beanvar = new UserBean();
beanvar.setUID(uid);
session.setAttribute("somename", beanvar);
```

In another servlet,

```
UserBean beanvar = (UserBean)session.getAttribute("somename");
if(beanvar != null)
{ 
   String uid = beanvar.getUid();
  ... 
}
```